# How would an AI visualize a story written in natural language?

Tags: natural-language-processing, image-generation

Can AI transform natural language text describing real scenarios to visual images and videos ? How does as AI interprets say a Harry Potter story if it has to reproduce it in form of videos ? Would be useful if anyone can help me with the required literature for understanding text to image transformation by AI